# Stop updatting DetailsView based on IF condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `DetailsView` with connected `SqlDataSource` and I want cancel updating row when my condition is true in `OnRowUpdating` event 
I did this step but when condition is true `DetailsView` still at editing mode all I need to return to normal view if the condition is true

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // Iterates through the rows of the GridView control
    foreach (DetailsViewRow row in DetailsView1.Rows)
    {
        // Selects the text from the TextBox
        // which is inside the GridView control
        // Selects the text from the DropDownList
        // which is inside the GridView control
        string dropDownListText = ((DropDownList)
           row.FindControl("DropDownList12")).SelectedItem.Text;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

        conn.Open();
        cmd2.CommandText = @"Select StatusID from ComplainMain Where TicketID=@tktid";
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tktid", ticketid.tktid);
        cmd2.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        int status;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            status = rdr.GetInt32(0);
            if (status == 3)
            {
                Label18.Visible = true;
                Label18.Text = "Can not Modify this Complaint as Ticket Closed refer to the Admin";
                e.Cancel = true;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Page_Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label18.Visible = false;

    DetailsView1.ItemUpdating += new DetailsViewUpdateEventHandler(DetailsView1_ItemUpdating);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ChangeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.changemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on your DetailsView

```
DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
```